# How to make a clickable responsive square box with centered content?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of columns each containing a square box that fills to the column width and maintains a square height ratio.

The entire box needs to be clickable, with the content inside that also centered within the box. I can't figure out a way of getting the inner `<a>` element to fill out the space inside the parent div and have its own content centered.

[Here is an editable Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdL87swm/)

The entire square should be red, entirely clickable, and with a centered download button within.

I've reviewed a bunch of similar questions about making square boxes with CSS but didn't find anything about the inner elements filling out the box like this.

Thanks

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #600;
}
.block a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #C00;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.block span {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

/* Demo only */
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.column {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Download</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Download</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Download</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Download</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the parent `.block` to `position: relative` allows us to set `.block > a` to `position: absolute`, with dimensions that fill its parent; I only added 3 css rules, they're commented so you know which ones:

```css
.block {
  position: relative; /* change #1 */
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #600;
}
.block a {
  position: absolute; /* change #2 */
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; /* change #3 */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #C00;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.block span {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

/* Demo only */
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.column {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Download</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Download</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Download</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">
      <a href="#">
        <span>Download</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could share an updated fiddle too ;) https://jsfiddle.net/2pdcf5e1/ ops code made it easy to finalize and it's not much to add to easily understood for the op. good job!

Comment: Thanks. I know this technique but didn't think to use it here in combination with flex for some reason.